# Apache RocketMQ in Service Fabric giving exception

Tags: rocketmq

I am using RocketMQ in service Fabric Application.
But it is throwing exception when i am tring to create instance of ONSFactoryProperty; ONSFactoryProperty factoryInfo = new ONSFactoryProperty()

```
External component has thrown an exception.

at ons.UnmanagedONSFactoryProperty.{ctor}(UnmanagedONSFactoryProperty* )
at ons.ONSFactoryProperty..ctor() in d:\bug\rocketmq-
client4cpp\managedons\managedonsfactory.cpp:line 8
```

Also at the time of create instance of ONSFactory ;
 ONSFactory onsfactory = new ONSFactory();

```
at ons.UnmanagedONSFactory.getInstance()
at ons.ONSFactory..ctor() in d:\bug\rocketmq-
client4cpp\managedons\managedonsfactory.cpp:line 271
```

But same code i have tried in console application.There it is working fine.Is there any solution for the issue?